# How can I track the distribution of iota?

Tags: snapshot, distribution

I am interested to follow the distribution from iota. 
Can we evaluate the IOTA distribution only after a snapshot?
And how it is done?

Something like [this](https://medium.com/@IngoFiedler_96862/iota-distribution-update-after-snapshot-from-08th-august-2017-21e92cf15eea).
[image: IOTA distribution]

Comment: Why the Downvote? Isn't it a valid question?

Comment: It wasn't me but from the first visual impression the down vote is not surprising. Questions should be able to stand on their own and be based on a problem. Add a few sentences about the distribution, what's the evaluation and what's your problem and include key parts from the blog you linked into your question. The way it currently looks it just seems extremely lazy, which won't encourage people to invest in an answer—or even trying to understand your problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is https://thetangle.org/statistics/tokens-distribution which shows some current token distribution stats.

When there was a snapshot, you can download `Snapshot.txt` and analzye it yourself (there is one line for each address, with address and balance).

When there is no recent snapshot, you can run a full node, add [Snapshot.ixi](https://github.com/iotaledger/Snapshot.ixi), and call it (just for yourself) whenever you need a new snapshot to analyze.